# How to solve ConnectionNotFoundException in JavaME

Tags: netbeans, java-me, io

I'm trying to connect to the internet via my J2ME application on my Netbeans emulator with the following function which connects to a webpage and prints out its HTML using `System.out.println()`.

```
function getHTML(String url)
{
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try
    {
        httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        int respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (respCode == httpConn.HTTP_OK)
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
            is = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
            int chr;
            while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
                sb.append((char) chr);

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error " + respCode);
        }
        httpConn.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I've been getting the following error;

```
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 10051 in socket::open
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open0(), bci=0
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.connect(), bci=209
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open(), bci=216
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.openPrim(), bci=4
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.createConnection(), bci=41
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(), bci=41
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=164
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=7
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=33
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.getResponseCode(), bci=5
```

I know my code isn't the problem because this used to work on my old laptop, but it hasn't worked since I installed Netbeans on my new laptop. Is it because of my internet connection, or my firewall settings, or my settings in Netbeans, or did I just not install Netbeans properly?

Comment: please check your `url` string and internet connection

Comment: If you have "localhost" in the URL try changing it to "127.0.0.1". I saw in a NetBeans ticket earlier that this had been an issue in v6.0, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send some data and receive means then try the coding

```
try
{
        httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        os = httpConn.openOutputStream();

        //Writing data to os
        os.write(b);        //Here b is a byte array
        os.flush(); 
        int respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (respCode == httpConn.HTTP_OK)
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            is = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
            int chr;
            while ((chr = is.read()) != -1)
                sb.append((char) chr);

            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error " + respCode);
        }

    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(os!=null) os.close();
    if(is!=null) is.close();
    if(httpConn!=null) httpConn.close();
    os=null;is=null;httpConn=null;
}
```